# concatenate multiple input iterations into a single string

Tags: python, string, concatenation

Apologies if this has been asked, but the similar questions I found weren't answering my problem exactly.

I know how to take a single input and convert it into a string, and or anything hard coded. What I'm trying to do however is take multiple inputs and convert them into a single string.

Example:

```
Enter a letter: h
Enter a letter: e
Enter a letter: l
Enter a letter: l
Enter a letter: o
```

...and so on, however long it takes until the user inputs 's' for instance.

```
Enter a letter: s
```

And then the program prints all previous iterations as a single string.

```
Result: hello
```

How do I piece together a string from separate, potentially infinite inputs?

Answer (score 1):

I realize this post is old, however, this is how I coded the solution in Python 3

```
mylist = []
results = ""
while True:
    c = input("Enter a letter:")
    if c == "s":
        result = "\n".join(mylist)
        print('Items entered: \n'+ result)
        break
    mylist.append(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I piece together a string from separate, potentially infinite inputs?

You can do this using

```
''.join(inputs)
```

where `inputs` is any [iterable](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterable) of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your inputs result in a list (or any other iterable) of characters (or strings), as you would get from, for example:

```
mylist = []
while True:
   c = raw_input("Enter a letter:")
   if c == "s":
       break
   mylist.append(c)
```

then you can simply `join()` them:

```
result = "".join(mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
''.join(iter(lambda: raw_input('Enter a letter: '), 's'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = []

while len(my_list) == 0 or my_list[-1] != 's':
    my_list.append(raw_input("Enter a letter: "))

print ''.join(my_list[:-1])
```